# Extract Json response Create dynamic variables and assign values

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to extract values from a json response and assign the values to variables and use them in subsequent requests.

Request 1 Response

```
{
  "XXX":"Test Company 1",
  "YYY":"Test Company 2",
  "ZZZ":"Test Company 3"
}
```

I want to create dynamic variables and values like below.

```
Company_Name_1 = "Test Company 1"
Company_Code_1 = "XXX"
Company_Name_2 = "Test Company 2"
Company_Code_2 = "YYY"
Company_Name_3 = "Test Company 3"
Company_Code_3 = "ZZZ"
```

and use above variables in subsequent requests like below.

Request 2 Parameter

```
{
    "Date": "${MeetingDate}",
    "StartTime": "${StartTime}",
    "EndTime": "${EndTime}",
    "InvestorsByDate": [{
        "Name": "${Company_Name_1}",
        "Code": "${Company_Code_1}"
    },
    {
        "Name": "${Company_Name_2}",
        "Code": "${Company_Code_2}"
    },
    {
        "Name": "${Company_Name_3}",
        "Code": "${Company_Code_3}"
    }]
}
```

Total number of companies is not a constant, its changing continuously. So i need to write a code to capture the dynamic values and assign them to dynamically created variables then use them in subsequent requests. I am totally new to scripting. Please help me to face this challenge. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is response from Request 1 always the same in terms of structure?

Comment: No its changing continuously based on our selection. I have used Regular Expression extractor and used -1 to collect all the values. Now i want to iterate through the variables and add them in Request 2 parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcesor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the first request
2. Make sure you have `groovy` as a language and tick `Cache compiled script if available` box
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   def companies = new JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
   def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
   jsonBuilder {
       "Date"   vars.get('MeetingDate')
       "StartTime" vars.get('StartTime')
       "EndTime" vars.get('EndTime')
       "InvestorsByDate" companies.collect {
           [
               Name: it.getValue(),
               Code: it.getKey()
           ]
       }
   }
   vars.put('requestBody', jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
   log.info('Generated body: ' + vars.get('requestBody'))
   ```
4. You will be able to refer the generated JSON Payload as `${requestBody}` or `${__V(requestBody)}` where required

Demo:

[image: JMeter Generate JSON]

References:

- Groovy - [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [JsonBuilder documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitri T Thank you, It's very useful, I did a modification and working as expected.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

    def companies = new JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
    def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
    jsonBuilder {"InvestorsByDate"companies.collect{[IdString: it.getKey(),Name: it.getValue()]}
    }
    vars.put('InvestorsByDate', jsonBuilder.toString())
    vars.put('InvestorsByDate', vars.get('InvestorsByDate').substring(1))
    vars.put('InvestorsByDate', vars.get('InvestorsByDate').substring(0,vars.get('InvestorsByDate').length() - 1))

    log.info(vars.get('InvestorsByDate'))
```

I need one more help, please do if possible. Is it possible to change company name like below.

```
"InvestorsByDate": [{
    "Name": "1. Company Name1",
    "Code": "Company_Code_1"
},
{
    "Name": "2. Company Name2",
    "Code": "Company_Code_2"
},
{
    "Name": "3. Company Name3",
    "Code": "Company_Code_3"
}]
```

I want to concat number with company name. Is it possible in json builder?

Comment: You must ask this in another question. Thanks!

Comment: Oh.. Thank u for notifying me.